"I rarely purchase concessions at the theater", with "concessions" in the sense of "products we buy at the concessions"
Today I came across this sentence:

Moviegoing isn't my thing, so I rarely purchase concessions at the theater.

I looked up "concession" and it has the meaning of "the right to sell something in a particular place; the place where you sell it, sometimes an area that is part of a larger building or store".
In the above sentence, concession doesn't mean "the place to sell products", but "the products".
So I'm wondering if concession also means "the products we sell at concessions".

Odd use of the word,  please link to the source.

But here is another source that uses "concessions" to mean "popcorn and drinks etc" https://www.statista.com/outlook/amo/media/cinema/cinema-concessions/united-kingdom#analyst-opinion

and indeed wiktionary has "(chiefly US, usually in the plural) An item sold within a concession (see above) or from a concessions stand."

Note that this usage is not common in BrE. The quote is clearly US though, from spelling and use of theatre rather than cinema. It might be better marked as such.

I've never heard any moviegoer in the US call the popcorn, candy, and softdrinks "concessions". Sounds more like a bookkeeping category or a business term used when analyzing a theater's income.

It's a weird sentence, some very formal language mixed with the informal "my thing". Possibly the use of "concession" is deliberate for some literary purpose, it sounds very arch and condescending. I think "snacks" or "food" would be more usual in this context. And "buy" (informal) not "purchase" (formal). (In a business-related document it would be less weird.)

Although AMC cinemas offers the equally bizarre "AMC goes far beyond classic concessions like popcorn and fountain drinks to give you an absolutely appetizing experience." (Someone likes alliteration?) So I guess it has some currency in the industry, even if it's not something a regular person would say.

I’m voting to close this question because to buy a concession means to buy the right [to sell certain things]. It doesn't mean buying the things a concession-holder sells.

The technical term is Concession Stand. Except: people go and actually buy popcorn, etc. No one says buys concessions! To purchase a concession is usually lands with concession rights. This question should not be closed precisely due to the misunderstanding between the movie house use of a concession stand/area and the legal use. For pete's sake.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concession definition 3b This is bog standard in NE US. This comment thread illustrates a weakness of ELL.

@Yorik No, it does not go into detail on the cultural uses of the term per se. Someone is serially downvoting me.

If you used the word "concessions" in a British cinema you'd probably get laughed at

Yes, as noted in the comments, in some regional dialects of American English, "concessions" can mean foods or drinks sold at a concession stand - which is a booth, cart, or small shop that sells street food and beverages for sporting events, arts events (such as movies, plays, or concerts), or recreational locations (such as at a park or county fair). Personally, I know that this term is common in the Northeast region of the US, and may also be popular elsewhere.
Common foods that would be sold at a concession stand (and thus described as concessions) include:

popcorn
hot dogs
hamburgers
candy
chips and other pre-packaged snacks
hot pretzels
soda pop
lemonade
water
(possibly) beer (depending on the event)
(possibly) ice cream bars, cones, or milkshakes (depending on facilities available)


It is in all American English. Not some regional dialects. Concessions in movie theater, stadiums, etc.  is an industry-wide term.

Concession(s), the industry term, concession stand and concession counter or concession(s) are very well known to moviegoers in the US. However, buy concessions is simply not said. You buy popcorn or soft drinks (and now many other snack-type items) at a concession counter. Sometimes, movie theaters will have a notice that comes up on the screen about the concession stand before the feature film begins and before other local advertising.
You go to a concession stand to buy snacks (and recently fancier things).
For example:

“It is things like concessions and how that fits into a broader movie
theater experience that really are things that movie theaters need to
focus on and hammer in,” Gallinari said. “Not only is that the part of
the experience they can control, but that’s more of the revenue they
can control since movie theater box office [performances] are variable
based on the movie.”

AND:

Theaters generate significantly more profitability from concessions,
with some large chains pulling in more than 40% of their revenue from
food and beverage.

upscale food at movie theaters
So, a moviegoer would not be in the habit of saying I'm "buying concessions". The moviegoer just buys popcorn or nachos or candy or soft drinks there but does not go around using the term. Concession is however the industry term for that in a movie theater.
Except perhaps in this kind of exchange:
Mark: Where's Johnny, Tim? Tim: He's over by the concession stand.
Finally, in issues of land rights where oil drilling or mining is taking place, the word concession is used to mean a kind of lease to the people carrying out the mining or drilling. People obtain concession rights in exchange for money in order to use the resource.
This question was answered with regard to movies, as given in the question. Obviously, concession stands are also common in sports' stadiums and other places where the owner of the stand has to pay rent to the venue owner in order to sell their wares.
And to go all the way here, in that sense, a concession is just like oil drilling. You rent a space on which you conduct business and pay the owners of the space or land to do so.

Ignore the downvoting. It's wrong.

That's interesting, I wonder if this is a regional difference? I have frequently heard "Do you want any concessions?" used interchangeably with "Do you want anything from the concession stand?" or with "Do you want any snacks?"

@FriendlyRacoon Well, I have never heard that. Only Do you want popcorn? Or a drink, or candy. I just don't think people go around using that term much.
